# gtk_events_pending() returns FALSE with events still pending

Tags: c, gtk

I'm working on an application that has a start and stop button. These buttons block the UI, and for various reasons, I can't spawn a thread.

I've been showing a working screen when these buttons are pressed, using:

```
while (gtk_events_pending()) gtk_main_iteration();
```

which ensures that the working screen is loaded before the start/stop operations begin.

I've recently upgraded to GTK+ 3.8.6, and it seems that `gtk_events_pending()` is now broken. Now, sometimes the window shows, but the image in the window isn't there. Sometimes the window doesn't even show.

The function in question looks like:

```
gtk_widget_show(working_screen);
while (gtk_events_pending()) gtk_main_iteration();

long_running_blocking_function();
```

If I do something like:

```
int busy_wait = 0;
gtk_widget_show(working_screen);
while (gtk_events_pending() || busy_wait < 5) 
{
    gtk_main_iteration();
    if (!gtk_events_pending()) ++busy_wait;
}

long_running_blocking_function();
```

...it works fine. However, I know it's only a matter of time until the busy_wait needs to be longer so I'd like to find a better answer. Has anybody experienced this issue? Does anybody have any ideas about how I might work around it?

Comment: Please add more code, this is not sufficient to investigate your issue. A minimal example - as always - is the best thing you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `g_main_context_pending(NULL)` and `g_main_context_iteration(NULL,FALSE)` instead of `gtk_events_pending()`, the later is deprecated.

---

It could be a timing issue that kicks in (it oculd be that your loop kicks in before any events are registered to the mainloop, and thus instantly exits) - but this is just wild guessing due to lack of code.

---

The break condition is also wrong, you do not want to exit as soon as all events are processed at a specific point of time, you want to continue until long-run-ops are done.
That means you need to signal when your operation is done, check that flag in the loop you currently use and use blocking mode of the `*_iteration(...)`

Comment: I tried switching out my calls to `gtk_main_pending()` and `gtk_main_iteration()`, however I'm seeing the same behavior. Given that I'm looping right after I add the event, I can see how it might be a timing issue. I'm not sure what the best way to wait for GTK to register the event is though.

Comment: If `long_running_blocking_function();` consists of chunks, `use gtk_main_context_iteration(NULL, FALSE);` inbetween these chunks. If it is really a single undividable piece, do it a thread (i.e. `GThread`).

Comment: Peppering my code with the `gtk_main_iteration()` calls seems to have helped.

Comment: @drahnr I cannot find any claim that `gtk_events_pending` is deprecated. At least it is not deprecated in gtk+3 stable. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-events-pending

Comment: The post is 3 years old, smetimes API gets resurrected from deprecation. Tbh, I don't know, and you should check things out yourself and rely on a 3 year old post.