# What's the proper way to end gtk without gtk_main()?

Tags: c, gtk

I have written a small gtk program, but I am not using `gtk_main()`.  Rather I am run `gtk_main_iteration()` as long as there are events to service and then run my own update function, like this:

```
while (active) {
    while ( gtk_events_pending() ) gtk_main_iteration();
    update();
}
```

Since there is no `gtk_main()`, `gtk_main_quit()` will be useless.

```
g_signal_connect(window,"destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
```

**So what should I do when I register the destroy signal?**

If I don't handle the destroy signal, my code tries to continue, but fails because the gtk hierarchy no longer exists, yet something in some still existing part of gtk raises this same exception 7 times:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handler_disconnect: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

I can call my own G_CALLBACK function that simply calls `exit()` and then the exceptions don't occur, but that doesn't give me the opportunity to cleanly handle application shutdown.

Comment: Just set `active` to `false`, ending the loop. And check if the program is still active before calling code that depends on GTK(I assume `update`?). e.g `while(active) {... if(active) update(); }`. By the way I'm not much of C programmer but I think you can pass a pointer to `active` to the gsignal so you can set it on callback without relying on globals.

Comment: read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271484/gtk-events-pending-returns-false-with-events-still-pending