# Sleep function suspends Gtk3 main iteration

Tags: perl, event-handling, sleep, gtk3

I have this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk3 '-init';
my $error_window = Gtk3::Window->new('toplevel');
my $er_label = Gtk3::Label->new('NOPE');
$error_window->add($er_label);
$er_label->show();
$error_window->set_size_request(800,300);
$error_window->set_position('center-always');
$error_window->show_all();
while ($er_label->get_text() eq 'NOPE') {
   while (Gtk3::events_pending()) {Gtk3::main_iteration();};
   sleep 4;
   $er_label->set_text('OK');
}
$error_window->signal_connect('key_press_event', sub { Gtk3::main_quit(); });
Gtk3::main();
```

it is pretty simple but it exhibits strange behaviour. I expected it to display first label 'NOPE', then sleep for 4 seconds, then change label to 'OK'. However, what I got is this: it displays black window, then sleeps for 4 seconds, then displays label 'OK'.

Why does it seem that `sleep` prevents Gtk3 from processing all events?

This line `while (Gtk3::events_pending()) {Gtk3::main_iteration();};` should force Gtk3 to evaluate all events sent to the main loop before the `sleep 4` is called.

Comment: Maybe check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21271484/1592377) question? Could be your problem.

Comment: In the end the only proper way to do this is to do the sleep (or whatever it is a placeholder for) in a seperate thread though. The update of the label will have to be done in the main thread, but there are ways of dispatching functions to the main thread to be called when it's idle, you should be able to find how to do that with a bit of searching.

Answer (score 3):

You should never sleep in the GTK main loop, this will freeze the thread in which it is running. Luckily the developers of GTK realized that people sometimes want to do delay some functions calls, so they added the timeout function `Glib::Timeout->add(` which will call a given function every *n* ms until the function returns `True`.

An example can be found in the [GTK3 Perl tutorial](https://github.com/kevinphilp/Perl-gtk3-Tutorial/blob/master/pong.pl#L53) where it is used to update their Pong game every 20 ms while the GTK main loop is running. Below the relevant line:

```
Glib::Timeout->add( 20, \&update );
```